# How to list time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with timestamps. I want to list the data in chronologically, but for each "id" separately. So, put timestamps in ascending order for id=2. When the last id=2 entry is reached, start listing id=3 entries,etc.

Data:

```
df
timestamp         id   value
2022-10-10 00:00   2     221
2022-10-10 00:00   3     189
2022-10-10 00:05   8     140
...
2022-10-19 15:14   2     143
2022-10-19 16:43   8     99
```

Desired output:

```
df
timestamp         id   value
2022-10-10 00:00   2     221
....               2
2022-10-19 15:14   2     143
2022-10-10 00:00   3     189
....               3
2022-10-11 21:32   3     202
2022-10-10 00:05   8     140
...                8
2022-10-19 16:43   8      99
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does `df.sort_values(['id', 'timestamp'])` work?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this using groupby and sort_values.

```
df = df.groupby(['id'])
sorted_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))
```

If you are only interested in the top values, you can play around with .head() functions as well.

Good luck!